# What thread synchronization mechanisms are available in VB6

Tags: multithreading, vb6, thread-safety

What thread synchronization mechanisms are available in VB6?

Comment: Are you looking for builtin language features, or are WinAPI calls ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None natively, If you do threading in VB6, you'll iether have to make heavy use of the threading Windows API functions (for good info on this see Dan Applemans books or the Matthew Curland book "Power Techniques for Everyday Programmers")

You can also do threading via COM via timers and COM apartment threading, but that also requires quite a bit of framework code, and even then, you still have to code the synch functionality yourself.

Comment: Also be aware that using the Windows threading functions can make the IDE very unstable and prone to crashing often, especially if you use the "Stop" button to terminate code that is running in a thread. Using raw threads can also make a compiled VB6 app pretty unstable. Simulating true multi-threading using ActiveX EXE's and timers is generally the only "safe" way to do multi-threading in VB6.

Comment: +1 on Mike's comment. You can't do much interactive debugging if you go the API route.

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in thread synchronization mechanisms - use Win32 API calls to access built-in windows synchronization mechanisms. See [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3x8b09y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Why do you ask a question only to answer it yourself just 2 minutes later ?

Comment: I couldn't find the answer online, so when I found the answer I thought I might as well document it http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to